# Php - XML Schema version

Tags: php, xml, schema

I'm searching for a while for what version xsd support php (5.3.0) has, but I haven't found anything. :S I'm trying to use xsd:assert in a schema with php, but I haven't managed it yet. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP supports XSD through `libxml2` library, which may not support this yet.

http://xmlsoft.org/